# How to get column name on column filter click

Tags: kendo-grid

I have to create filter menu with values displayed in dropdown list for that particular column.

I have added

```
filterable:
             {
                   ui: colFilter,
                   extra: false
              }

function colFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: ["Yes", "No"],
        optionLabel: 'Select'
    })
}
```

while creating the columns.

What I want is how can I get the column title and field name when the function colFilter is called. So I can try to get the column values for that particular column.

Any other solution is welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: So got this working. Found solution for this. We need to modify the ui method as below.                                       filterable: { 
        ui: $.proxy(colFilter, { field: "ID" }) 
    }. Then in the colFilter method we need to get the value of the clicked column as this.field. So in our example it will give value as ID. If there is any other requirement like we need to pass some additional parameter to the method we can pass that also like below. ui: $.proxy(colFilter, { field: "ID" , anyName : '1' }). We can get the value as var val = this.anyName in the colFilter method. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So got this working. Found solution for this over internet. So posting the solution here in case if onyone needs this.

We need to modify the ui method as below.

```
filterable: { ui: $.proxy(colFilter, { field: "ID" }) }.
```

Then in the colFilter method we need to get the value of the clicked column as

```
this.field.
```

So in our example it will give value as ID.

If there is any other requirement like we need to pass some additional parameter to the method we can pass that also like below.

```
ui: $.proxy(colFilter, { field: "ID" , anyName : '1' }).
```

We can get the value as

```
var val = this.anyName
```

in the colFilter method.

Thanks.